# PSEXEC will copy .bat file but wont run it on remote computer?

Tags: windows, batch-file, psexec

i have looked around a fair bit, but cant seem to find an answer to this.
I am creating a script that is a part of the off boarding process for our company. As part of the process, it grants permssion for another user to access the exiting users profile share (working fine). The next part will map a network drive remotely (im having trouble with this. I am using PSEXEC to dispatch a bat script which maps the users drive:

```
    @echo off
::Welcome note
echo Welcome to the User EXIT script!
:Start

:: set variable to be used throughout script for the username of the person exiting.

set /p uname="Please enter the username for exit:"
set /p cleanupu="Please enter the username for homedrive & mailbox cleanup:"
set /p computermap="Please enter the Computer to clean up the Homedrive:"
echo The username for exit is: %uname%
echo The username that is cleaning up is: %cleanupu%
echo The computer for the homedrive to be mapped to is %computermap%
set /P c=Is this correct [Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :init_confirm
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :start

:init_confirm

::confirmation....

echo This script will exit the user: %uname%
pause
icacls "\\server\home$\%uname%" /grant DOMAIN\%cleanupu%:(OI)(CI)F
pause
echo net use z: \\server\home$\%uname%\ > map_temp.bat

psexec \\%computermap% -c -i -d map_temp.bat

pause
exit
```

This will copy the file to the remote computer and open up a blank command prompt window.

Can anyone see why this wont actually run map_tem.bat?

cheers

Comment: Not sure, but you could try `wmic /node:%computermap% process call create "net use z: \\\\server\\home$\\%uname%"` as an alternative to `psexec`.  If authentication is needed, then `wmic /node:%computermap% /user:domain\username /password:password process etc...`

Comment: Even if you get the batch script to run, it won't actually work, because it isn't running in the user's logon session.  Network drives are mapped on a per-logon-session basis.  With local system privilege, it is possible to break into the user's logon session (search term: WtsQueryUserToken) but not from a batch file.

Comment: Also, note that there's no need to use a batch file to run a single line; you could have just said: `psexec \\%computername% net use z: \\server\home$\%uname%`